# WP7 BackgroundAudioAgent: get Meta data from Icecast

Tags: windows-phone-7, metadata, icecast, background-audio

I have a Windows Phone project that streams radio stations from an Icecast server. 
I am using Background Audio Agent to play the streams.

The Icecast stream provides Track Title - Artist name as the metadata.

Is there any way I can fetch the metadata from the Audio Player?

Right now I am fetching the metadata from a PHP script every 10 secs. If I get it directly from Icecast, it will be good.

In my IPhone application I am able to see the metadata. I am using the video player in IPhone app.

Tell me whether it can be done or not.

If not, please tell me whether I can read the stream byte by byte and send it to the Audio agent.

Thanks.